# Google apps script for conditional formatting table cells in google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've contacted @mhawksey via Twitter and he gave me this...
[Remove row of table in a Google Document with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682922/remove-row-of-table-in-a-google-document-with-google-apps-script/46244042#46244042)

Which gives me a look into scripting for a DOC not a SHEET (I've only ever scripted SHEETS before) however it doesn't give me what I'm going for.

I'd like to be able conditionally format table cells based on values entered via a mail merge. I"m sure there'll be a simple script that can handle this. If someone can start me off with what values I need to read and the first 'if' statement I should be able to carry on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the Document (DocumentApp.openById or DocumentApp.create or DocumentApp.openByUrl), you're going to have to get the Body, search for Tables, and then process their TableCells.

Something like:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl([URL]);  
var body = doc.getBody();  
var tables = body.getTables();

for each (var table in tables) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) {
        var row = table.getRow(i);

        var j;
        for (j = 0; j < row.getNumCells(); j++) {
            var cell = row.getCell(j);

            // formatting goes here
            // example based on a numeric cell and a threshold of 50
            if (cell.getValue() > 50) {
                cell.setBackgroundColor("#ff0000");
            } else {
                cell.setBackgroundColor("#00ff00");
            }

            // Define a custom paragraph style.
            // can be used for more complicated formatting
            var style = {};
            style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] =
                 DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;
            style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
            style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
            style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
            cell.setAttributes(style);
        }    
    }             
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for responding Richard! I've popped the Doc URL in and run a debug. However the setColour() attribute isn't recognised. I can't find how to attach a screenshot on this comment.

Comment: Sorry - I think I meant setBackgroundColor() there.  

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#

Comment: AMAZING! Okay so I've given the formatting I need for the intended output however I need some IF statements in there that look at the cell contents and format based on what it finds. I've looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404002/google-apps-script-conditional-if-else-if-statement but I'm not sure which bit of the code you've supplied I need to compare. Thanks!

Comment: This is starting to sound like an undisclosed homework question, but you need an if statement testing the value of the cell against your criteria.

Say the cell is a number, and above 50 is different than below 50:

if (cell.getValue() > 50) {
cell.setBackgroundColor("#ff0000");
} else {
cell.setBackgroundColor("#00ff00");
}

Comment: I wish I could set stuff like this for homework! I'm a teacher! My coding knowledge is very infantile but I'm getting there. Generally I need some starting guidance and I can find my way from there. This is great thank you!