# How can I delete empty columns from a table in a Google Slides presentation with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I have a google apps script that copies data from a google sheet into a copy of a google slides template. Data is copied into a placeholder table in the slides template, so sometimes there are extra blank rows in the table on the slide, depending on what was entered in the sheet.

Does anybody know of a way to delete extra rows from a table on a google slide using google apps script?

I see [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682922/remove-row-of-table-in-a-google-document-with-google-apps-script/46244042#46244042?newreg=46aa7b15420a4c58b5525923a4b01e7b) for doing the same thing on a google docs table, but it doesn't look like the [Presentation class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#replaceAllText(String,String)) has a getTables() method as used in that answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Suggestion

You can try this sample Google Slides [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) below, where it checks each rows on the slide presentation table and then it deletes all detected empty rows:

### Sample Script

```
function removeEmptyRow() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0]; //Get the first slide
  var table = presentation.getTables()[0]; //Get the first table on the slide

  for(var col=0; col <= table.getNumColumns()-1; col++){
    for(var row=0; row<=table.getNumRows()-1; row++){
      var cellValue = table.getCell(row,col).getText().asString();
      if(cellValue.length == 1){ //check if current row is emtpy
        Logger.log("Row #"+row+" in column #"+col+" is empty");
        table.getRow(row).remove(); //remove this row index on the table
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### References:

[**Class TableRow**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table-row)

**[Class Slides getTables()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#gettables)**

### Sample Result

> **Sample Slide Presentation table**

[image]

> After running the script:

[image]

> 2 empty rows were removed from the table

[image]